# The meaning of “Jetzt gibt's aber Krach. Jetzt schlägt's aber dreizehn”

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom

What is the meaning of the following sentences?

> Jetzt gibt's aber Krach. Jetzt schlägt's aber dreizehn.

I saw the meaning in a book as

> That's the limit. I won't put up with this any longer.

But could  you please give a better answer and more details about these sentences?

Comment: http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Jetzt%20schlaegt%27s%20%2F%20schlaegt%20es%20dreizehn!&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Jetzt gibt's aber Krach

Should be somewhat obvious - *We're just about getting into a (loud) argument. (And I'm starting this **now**)*

> Jetzt schlägt's 13

Based on the (BTW false[*]) assumption that church clocks will never announce the 13th hour, this is an example of something abnormally infamous, impossible that just happened - And we need to react to it.

[*] The [Straßburger Münster](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stra%C3%9Fburger_M%C3%BCnster#Astronomische_Uhr) clock has been known to announce the 13th hour since the 13th (sic) century and claims to be the only church clock in the world that does it.

Comment: And note that it is not a good idea if a grown-up says ‘jetzt schlägts dreizehn’ for the child to answer ‘nein, zwölf’ if it’s just approaching midnight. Source: Own experience.

Comment: Im Dom von Florenz gibt es noch immer eine Uhr mit 24-Stunden-Anzeige: http://www.florentinermuseen.com/foto/duomo/image/clock.jpg Solche Uhren gab es früher viele. (Es gab auch Uhren, bei denen die Zeiger sich entgegen dem heutigen Uhrzeigersinn drehten, oder bei denen der Stundenzeiger länger als der Minutenzeiger ist, z.B. Grazer Uhrturm) Mir ist nur nicht bekannt, ob es unter den 24-Stunden-Uhren auch welche mit einem Läutwerk gab, das z.B. um 17 Uhr 17-mal geschlagen hat.

Comment: 24 Stunden *anzeigen* kann jede moderne Digitaluhr. Dreizehn schlagen können dürften die wenigsten...